# How to find Button's DataContext in this sample code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I was going through the excellent blog written by Rachel. Here is the [link](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/).

She mentions in "The View" section that " As Button’s DataContext is the PageViewModel, she used a RelativeSource binding to find the ChangePageCommand". 
Could any one explain me, how is that Button's DataContext is PageViewModel?

She has written another blog explaining about DataContext [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). From this article it seemed to me that DataContext of the Button would be "ApplicationViewModel", because if the element's DataContext is not specified it will inherit DataContext of it's Parent. And as none of the elements specify any DataContext, it seems like DataContext of Button should be of Window element DataContext (which is "ApplicationViewModel" as defined in App.xaml.cs).

Obviously I am wrong here, but what is that I am not thinking correctly?

Other Code snippets can be found in the article, below is the XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMVVMExample.ApplicationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleMVVMExample"
    Title="Simple MVVM Example" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
        <local:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're inside of an ItemsControl's ItemTemplate. The DataContext is implicitly defined as the binding of each object provided by the ItemsSource binding collection.

The ItemsControl creates an ItemTemplate for each item in the ItemsSource collection.  The DataContext of each ItemTemplate will be bound to the individual object that is being iterated in the collection. You can read more about  datatemplate behavior [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.95).aspx). *(See Remarks)*

So, in order to get to the ChangePageCommand provided by the window's DataContext , you have to provide a relative source lookup.